# Magento Remove Shipping Steps in one step checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I used this tutorial - http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/removed-shipping-address-and-shipping-method-from-onepage-checkout-in-magento/ to remove the shipping steps in one page checkout. Now, when you order it skips the shipping steps, but it still shows those shipping steps. I want to remove them from the webpage, how can it be done ? 
Here is the screenshot to the page - http://imagebin.org/227116 , website url - http://homehero.in
Moreover, it takes more time to jump to next step (i.e while skipping the shipping steps).

Comment: Please don't use URL shortening services for your links, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup. And, your bit.ly link is broken, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try on this. http://sapnandu-magento.blogspot.com/2012/04/magento-onestep-checkout-remove.html